# Is there way to make .NET numeric formatter to use MidpointRounding.ToEven?

Tags: .net, formatting, ieee-754

Apparently, .Net Framework is not consistent with defaults in midpoint rounding. `Math.Round` and `Convert.ToInt32` will round to even, while `double.ToString` will round away from zero.

```
Math.Round(4.5) = 4;
4.5.ToString("#") = "5";
```

What's good about `Math.Round`, that you can make it round away from zero with extra parameter. What's bad about `ToString`, I wasn't able to find a way to make it round to even.

Sure I'd round it myself using `Math.Round`, but I need to know number of decimal places to round, and somehow I don't feel like parsing format string, which is external to my code.

So what can I do? May be some tricky `NumberFormatInfo`?

Comment: `Math.Round(4.5678, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)` does not suit you?

Comment: No, since I don't know precision needed. I'm just getting format string which may look like `'#.00'` or `'{0.0000;-0.0000;}:7'` or even `'F4'`. I'm not self-confident enough to get into parsing this stuff.

Comment: To get the number of significant figures: "The real way" http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/email/pdfq3pavhBfih.pdf, with inspiration here http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c "hack way" - use decimal number = 123.456m;
int decimalPlacesCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(argument)[3])[2];  //this gets the number of sigfigs after the comma most of the time and then round as you please (toeven even)

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea, thank you, buy your suggestions don't really help me, as my problem is not with unknown number of actual digits in the number, but rather in unknown number of digits used by format string. But still interesting to know, something new every day.

Comment: Read the article then! It might shine some light on the difficulty of what you want to achieve! Me, I would ban floating point math and modify all modern processors to use some form of decimal instead, evil float math is quite difficult even if you understand what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

If you parse a fixed number into your given format string you should get the amount of decimal points. 
because you know how many decimalpoints this number produces. 
ofc this is only valubel with a limited amount of decimal points.

lets say 100 decimal, you could use pi parse it into the given string and see where it ends

it would be something like this in the end:

```
private string ParseFormat(string format, decimal number)
{
    int decimalPlaces = Math.PI.ToString(format)
                       .Where(Char.IsDigit).Count();

    return Math.Round(number, 
                      decimalPlaces -1, //removes the leading 3
                      MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString(format);
}
```

This might not be the best solution but should help you with your problem, you probably have to expand it, so that you get leading zeros removed and all that stuff, before you extract your decimal points.